# What's this biplane built by a 16-year old?

Tags: aircraft-identification, biplane

I was told that this plane was built by a 16-year old in the 90s. Ever since, I've been bent on finding the specifications, name, etc., of this airplane with no success.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I don't know about this being from the 90s, but it sure looks like the [Laird Baby Biplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laird_Baby_Biplane) in the Florida Air Museum to me:

[image]
*On display at Florida Air Museum, Lakeland Linder Regional Airport, Florida* ([wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Laird_Baby_Biplane_replica.jpg))

The identifying features that I observe to be common between this picture and other pictures of the aircraft are the shape of the nose, the details along the fuselage, the shape and placement of the struts, the tanks beneath the top wing and the shape of the engine protrusion. I would also note that the Wikipedia page indicates that the specimen in the museum is a replica that was built in the 90s (whereas the original is from 1912).

Comment: Yess!..its is Laird baby biplane